# List<type> applications is not listed in postgres. Java, spring boot, jpa, hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm not familiar with using hibernate as much as I should be. I am able to Create a Job Post, I am also able to Send in an application for that. However, there seems to not be a connection between the two. The database has a "jobs_id" field, but the Job Post Table does not have a List applications field. I have done so many different combinations of code to figure this out and asked gpt 4 for help to no avail. See when I do a GET on postman for the candidates for the Job Post. Nothing shows up.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "applications", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email", "jobs_id"})})

public class Application {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "jobs_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonBackReference
private JobPosting jobPosting;



@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
public class JobPosting {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;



@OneToMany(mappedBy = "jobPosting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<>();
```

The Above code is the part that is not showing up in postgres. I saw another post on stackoverflow that faced a similar issue to this. But was not able to find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Job Post Table does not have a List applications field" < that is correct in 1:N relationship.

> ```
> JobPosting "owns many" Application 
> Many Application belong to "one" JobPosting
> ```

In database that is represented as a column (**id**) in ***applications*** table.
JPA then load all related applications with special query/(queries).

I would also recommend to have a look on FetchType which tells whether the list will be load directly when loading JobPosting or after you use *get method*. The default type as well as behavior depends on the particular implementation of JPA.

```
EAGER
Defines that data must be eagerly fetched.
LAZY
Defines that data can be lazily fetched.
```